# Laravel 5.x - Not able to use Modal::method() inside Model's Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In one controller this works:

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::find(1)->toArray();
```

But, in another controller I just created it doesn't:

```
$vehicles = Region::find(1)->toArray();
```

It says:

```
FatalErrorException in RegionController.php line 21:
Class 'App\Region' not found
```

But I'm including similar classes:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use DB;
use App\Vehicle;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\VehicleRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class VehicleController extends Controller
```

versus:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use DB;
use App\Region;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class RegionController extends Controller
```

And this works if I replace the original code with it:

```
$regions = DB::table('regions')->where('id', '=', 1)->get();
```

I created them both the same way using artisan, and added use App\ModelName, not sure what needs to be done in order to be able to use Region::method().  Any ideas what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your declarations seem to be accurate.  Run the ff in your project's root directory:

```
composer dumpautoload
```

Comment: Hi, I actually already tried that, but did it again anyway with no change

Answer (score 0):

Okay, brutal I screwed up generating the model and accidentally pluralized Region to Regions. Sigh!